# One progress bar for multiple file upload

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I'm trying to upload 2 images(one at a time)using NSURLSessionTask.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
              task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
   didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent
    totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent
totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend
{
if (self.imageName1 != nil && self.imageName2 != nil) 
    {
        float progress = (float)totalBytesSent / (float)totalBytesExpectedToSend;
        if (progress != 1.00)
        {
            // Calculate total bytes to be uploaded or the split the progress bar in 2 halves
        }
    }
    else if (self.imageName1 != nil && self.imageName2 == nil)
    {
        float progress = (float)totalBytesSent / (float)totalBytesExpectedToSend;
        if (progress != 1.00)
        [self.progressBar1 setProgress:progress animated:YES];
    }
    else if (self.imageName2 != nil && self.imageName1 == nil)
    {
        float progress = (float)totalBytesSent / (float)totalBytesExpectedToSend;
        if (progress != 1.00)
        [self.progressBar2 setProgress:progress animated:YES];  
    }
}
```

How can I use a single progress bar to show the progress in case of 2 image uploads ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use `NSProgress` which allows you to roll-up child `NSProgress` updates into one.

1. So define a parent `NSProgress`:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSProgress *parentProgress;
   ```
2. Create the `NSProgress` and tell the `NSProgressView` to observe it:

   ```
   self.parentProgress = [NSProgress progressWithTotalUnitCount:2];
   self.parentProgressView.observedProgress = self.parentProgress;
   ```

   By using `observedProgress` of the `NSProgressView`, when the `NSProgress` is updated, the corresponding `NSProgressView` will automatically be updated, too.
3. Then, for the individual requests, create individual child `NSProgress` entries that will be updated, e.g.:

   ```
   self.child1Progress = [NSProgress progressWithTotalUnitCount:totalBytes1 parent:self.parentProgress pendingUnitCount:1];
   ```

   and

   ```
   self.child2Progress = [NSProgress progressWithTotalUnitCount:totalBytes2 parent:self.parentProgress pendingUnitCount:1];
   ```
4. Then, as the individual network requests proceed, update their respective `NSProgress` with the total bytes thus far:

   ```
   self.child1Progress.completedUnitCount = countBytesThusFar1;
   ```

The updating of the `completedUnitCount` of the individual child `NSProgress` objects will automatically update the `fractionCompleted` of the parent `NSProgress` object, which, because you're observing that, will update your progress view accordingly.

Just make sure that the `totalUnitCount` for the parent to be equal to the sum of the `pendingUnitCount` of the children.