# UIProgressView with multiple progress

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I build a progress bar with multiple progress in ios ? 
I don't think it is possible with the [UIProgressView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprogressview?language=objc)

I am looking for something like this(UI only) : 
[image: progress bar]
Thanks !

Comment: Rob, you've answered the OPs question in comments. You should post your responses as an answer so he can accept them and we can up-vote them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard `UIProgressView` shows only one progress and if you're trying to capture the progress of multiple items, you will have a hierarchy of `Progress`/`NSProgress` objects. E.g. if uploading five files, you have five `Progress` objects, one for each upload, and then have a sixth `NSProgress`, which the `UIProgressView` observes, which has the other five as children. See *Creating a Tree of Progress Objects* in the [NSProgress class reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsprogress?language=objc#see-also). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36616538/1271826 for an example.

If you want a progress view that visually represents the respective progress of individual `NSProgress`, you'll have to do this yourself (or find a third party control that does this). But the standard `UIProgressView`will not do this for you.

But it's not hard. You can, for example, create a horizontal stack view, add one `UIProgressView` for each `NSProgress` that you want to track, set the respective widths of the `UIProgressView` subviews to be, for example, whatever percentage they represent of the overall tasks.

E.g. here is a horizontal stack view with three `UIProgressView` arranged subviews:

[image]

Having said that, I prefer the standard single, consolidated `UIProgessView` because the user can more easily see how far along they are. If you have a series of progress views like this, it's really hard to visually see "how much longer do I have" because you have to look at all the individual progress views and mentally figure it out (e.g. "the first looks like it's 50% done, the second is 66% done, the third is 75% done ... so exactly how far along is the whole thing?!?").

Anyway, here my Swift code to render the above. I know you're looking for Objective-C, but hopefully this is enough to illustrate the basic idea that can easily be implemented in either Swift or Objective-C:

```
class MultiProgressView: UIStackView {

    struct ProgressInfo {
        let progressView: UIProgressView
        let totalToken: NSKeyValueObservation
        let progressToken: NSKeyValueObservation
    }
    var progressInfo = [ProgressInfo]()
    var progressHandler: ((Double) -> Void)?

    var widthConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]?

    func add(_ progress: Progress, progressTintColor: UIColor = .blue, trackTintColor: UIColor? = nil) {
        let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .bar)
        progressView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        progressView.progressTintColor = progressTintColor
        progressView.trackTintColor = trackTintColor ?? progressTintColor.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        addArrangedSubview(progressView)
        progressView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 1)
        progressView.observedProgress = progress
        let totalToken = progress.observe(\.totalUnitCount) { [weak self] (_, _) in
            self?.updateWidths()
        }
        let progressToken = progress.observe(\.completedUnitCount) { [weak self] (_, _) in
            if let percent = self?.percent {
                self?.progressHandler?(percent)
            }
        }
        progressInfo.append(ProgressInfo(progressView: progressView, totalToken: totalToken, progressToken: progressToken))
        updateWidths()
    }

    private func updateWidths() {
        if let widthConstraints = self.widthConstraints {
            removeConstraints(widthConstraints)
        }

        let totalUnitCount = self.totalUnitCount
        guard totalUnitCount > 0 else { return }

        widthConstraints = progressInfo.map { progressInfo in
            let unitCount = progressInfo.progressView.observedProgress?.totalUnitCount ?? 0
            return NSLayoutConstraint(item: progressInfo.progressView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .width, multiplier: CGFloat(unitCount) / CGFloat(totalUnitCount), constant: 0)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.addConstraints(self.widthConstraints!)
        }
    }

    var totalUnitCount: Int64 {
        return progressInfo.reduce(Int64(0)) { $0 + ($1.progressView.observedProgress?.totalUnitCount ?? 0) }
    }

    var completedUnitCount: Int64 {
        return progressInfo.reduce(Int64(0)) { $0 + ($1.progressView.observedProgress?.completedUnitCount ?? 0) }
    }

    var percent: Double {
        return Double(completedUnitCount) / Double(totalUnitCount)
    }
}
```

And then to use it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let download1 = Download(...)
    let download2 = Download(...)
    let download3 = Download(...)

    mainProgressView.progressHandler = { [weak self] percent in
        self?.checkIfDone(percent: percent)
    }

    mainProgressView.add(download1.progress, progressTintColor: .blue)
    mainProgressView.add(download2.progress, progressTintColor: .green)
    mainProgressView.add(download3.progress, progressTintColor: .red)

    download1.startDownload()
    download2.startDownload()
    download3.startDownload()
}

private func checkIfDone(percent: Double) {
    if percent == 1 {
        print("done")
    }
}
```